# How do I pick iBus keyboard layouts on NixOS

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, nixos, input-method, ibus

All additions to list of keyboard layouts made with `ibus-setup` have no effect, and after launching `ibus-setup` there is no trace of them.

Having iBus enabled in `configuration.nix` means having no other layout but English, regardless of `services.xserver.layout`. And I want layouts like Polish, French Canadian QWERTY, Russian Phonetic. I also want to enable `uniemoji` and some pinyin IME, although i think i already discovered some `engines` attribute that enables me to add them.

I may use `nixos-unstable` and am happy with continuing to.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with ibus, but looking at https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#ibus I'd suggest `i18n.inputMethod.ibus.engines` – there are examples in docs.